# Webcam shows blank on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, hp, webcam

My web camera doesn't work on my HP zbook g9 with RTX A2000 on Ubuntu 22.04. It was working yesterday, but today it doesn't work. I tried it on an Ubuntu live USB and I have i3 window manager and GNOME, but the issue persists in all these platforms. I mainly use GNOME desktop environment.

This is how the output of the web camera looks like at the moment:

[image: output of the web camera]

output of `ls /dev/video*`:

```
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2  /dev/video3
```

For some reason I have 2 IR camera and 2 normal

output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0781:5571 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Fit
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 17ef:608d Lenovo Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0408:534c Quanta Computer, Inc. HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices -D`:

```
HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1

Driver Info:

    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
    Driver version   : 6.2.16
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera
    Serial           : 01.00.00
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
    Media version    : 6.2.16
    Hardware revision: 0x00000003 (3)
    Driver version   : 6.2.16
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags            : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000013: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable
```

output `guvcview`

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.7
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
control[0]:(unknown - 0x6) 0x980001 'User Controls'
control[12]:(unknown - 0x6) 0x9a0001 'Camera Controls'
```

I don't know what could be the problem. Maybe it's a hardware issue? The computer is less than 2 weeks old.

"""""" UPDATE """"""

There is a tiny switch i didn't notice above the webcam that i can swipe to physically block the webcam. That was the issue, nothing with the software

Silly me.